# Can't access Dashboard of a Multisite Wordpress. Chrome results in "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Tags: multisite, wp-config

I'm suffering with this problem for two days. Here is my envroiment:

I"m using Amazon EC2 with Ubuntu 16.04, I've installed LAMP, phpmyadmin, vsftpd and that's all.

Then I've configured one **clean Wordpress** installation and everything is working fine with my main site. But, when I've setup a Multisite, whenever I try to access the Dashboard of any subsite beside the primary one, in Chrome, it results in "*ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS*". In other browsers, I got similar issues. Its not a browser related problem.

When I try to access the subsite main page, ALL resources, like scripts and style.css, results in "404 (Not Found)". All I can see its content with no script/style loaded.

I've done everything right according to my research and all searches says my ".htaccess" and "wp-config.php" is right. Here is they:

**wp-config.php**

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'ec2-34-211-137-194.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I also found people with similar problems, but, when they fix something on .htaccess or 'wp-config.php', they got it working.

I tried this: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518723/wordpress-multisite-subsite-wp-admin-err-too-many-redirects) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/267589/wordpress-network-multisite-wp-admin-redirect-loop-err-too-many-redirects) (similar, but not worked for me)

I'm kinda lost in this problem. In Log Error of Apache, there is NOTHING related to ".htacess" problem or "too many redirects". I'm wondering if its something about apache configuration, but I dont where to look.

What can I do to fix my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Even using "subdirectorys", i got this error, so I had to configure a DNS with "*.mydomain.com" to multisite functions workout.